# Linear dependence of functionals (Intuition)

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to understand why the linear dependence theorem of functionals is true at an intuitive level. I know the proof given in Brezis's functional analysis book (lemma 3.2), where the Hahn-Banach theorem is used; despite all formal details of the proof are clear to me, I feel I don't understand the intuition underground.

Could you help me?

> **Linear Dependence Theorem:** Let $X$ be a vector space and let $\varphi, \varphi_1,..., \varphi_k$ be $(k+1)$ linear functionals on
> $X$ such that $ \bigcap_{i=1}^{k}ker(\varphi_i) \subseteq
>  ker(\varphi)$. Then there exist constants
> $\lambda,\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi=
>  \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i\varphi_i$.

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of natural to see when $X$ is a Hilbert space. Each $\varphi_j$ is of the form $$\varphi_j(x)=\langle x,y_j\rangle,\qquad \varphi(x)=\langle x,y\rangle.
$$
So $$\ker\varphi_j=\{y_j\}^\perp,\qquad \ker\varphi=\{y\}^\perp.$$
Then the condition becomes $$\{y\}^\perp\supset\bigcap_j\{y_j\}^\perp=(\operatorname{span}\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\})^\perp.$$ Taking orthogonals,
$$\{y\}\subset\operatorname{span}\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\}.$$